# Calculate window height on domready and resize (spotty results)

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div id="page-wrapper">
    <div id="page-wrapper-inner">

    </div>
</div>
```

The `page-wrapper` is right inside of the `<body>` tag, so a `min-height:100%` works just fine there, but `page-wrapper-inner` won't span the entire height (which I know). So, I currently have the following to calculate and append the window height on page-load and when the window is resized:

```
/**
 * Calculate window height based on document height to fill inner-wrapper
 */
function resizeFrame() {
    var h = $(document).height();
    $("#page-wrapper-inner").height(h);
}

jQuery.event.add(window, "load", resizeFrame);
jQuery.event.add(window, "resize", resizeFrame);
```

This works fine on page-load, but get inconsistent results when resizing the window (particularly making it larger). Anyone have any thoughts on why it is not re-calculating the height at all times? Thanks!

Comment: CSS 3 media query is the way to go for handling screen size and stuff.

Comment: Is a pretty empty comment if you're not willing to give an example, link, or concept...

Answer (score -1):

I tried it with a jsFiddle and it actually worked pretty good. But I've two suggestions.

1. Have you already made a console log in your function resizeFrame to see if its called when you resize the window?
2. It might help if you go for $(**window**).height(); instead of $(document).height();

If this doesnt give you a good result, please post your according css.

Comment: I ran a `console.log(h)` and came up with http://i49.tinypic.com/2qicvur.jpg which correctly showed the new heights as the browser got skinnier, but when expanding, it stuck on that larger value. `$(window).height()` unfortunately doesn't span the height of the entire page (cuts off the background if there is a scrollbar). Here's the css around that area: http://pastebin.com/D7qjLdhi Thanks!

Comment: OK I think I got something. I actually realized, that `$(document).height()` doesnt change the value on resize, IF the content height stays the same (sorry I havent already worked much with it). So I dont have your whole css but I added this `body { margin:0; }` and the value stayd constantly. In my test it was just increasing because it added every time body's margin to the height of the page wrapper inner. I really dont know if this helps, otherwise you have to explain me, what you really want to do.